# how to write an onclick function in order to prevent bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling

Evening guys, I have an issue where a have a `<td>` tag and a `<p>` tag inside of it, both have onclick events, this is a textbook situation of the `<p>` onclick running the `<td>` onclick rather than its own. from what i have researched on here and elsewhere i have come to the understanding that this is caused by bubbling. However aparently knowing is only half the battle because i can not seem to find a way to implement a fix for this issue. Here is how i am currently attempting to work around it

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>text</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jquery:

```
$(function(){
var show = function(){
    $('#editentry').css({'display': 'block'}); //this is column 3
}
//run var show on click
$('td p').click(function(event){
    show;
    event.stopPropagation();//stop bubbling
});
});//end function
```

i have also tried this:

```
$(function(){
var show = function(event){
    $('#editentry').css({'display': 'block'}); //this is column 3
    event.stopPropagation();
}
//run var show on click
     $('td p').click(show);
});//end function
```

from what i understand this should be working, sorry if i missed something simple, im a bit new to jquery and this seems to be a complicated subject. thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you make a fiddle demonstrating the problem? It looks like your code should work.

Comment: you missed the brackets on your call to show. I imagine the event is running fine (note that bubbling means it is called *as well as* the other events)

Comment: @dave accidentally left out the brackets on copy over. ill try to put a fiddle together

Comment: @Dave His second attempt doesn't have that problem.

Comment: yes, and the second attempt works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/gEL7F/ (?)

Comment: (again, this has nothing to do with propagation. The stopPropagation line is making no difference to the result)

Comment: @Nick You never clearly described the problem you're having. The code you posted doesn't even have a click handler for the `<td>`.

Comment: its essentially the same as the td p, a tad different, glad to know that my understanding was corerect though and i am on the right path. must be something else, ill buckle down and get to it. thaks for the reassurance guys.

Comment: @Dave  I GOT IT! for some ungodly reason it would not work with the .click handler so i changed it to mousedown and it works like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have should work fine. That's exactly how you use `stopPropagation`.

Here is an example to show how it stops the event from bubbling:

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <p>inside paragraph</p> outside paragraph
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){

  $('td').click(function(event){
    alert('cell');
  });
  $('td p').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('paragraph');
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/39n5X/

If you click on "inside paragraph" it will only show the "paragraph" message, and if you click on "outside paragraph" it will show the "cell" message instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your stop bubbling line with this:

```
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue=false);
event.stopPropagation ? event.stopPropagation() : (event.cancelBubble=true);
```

Comment: That won't make any difference, as the `event` object in a jQuery event handler always has the `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` methods.

Comment: yeah it made no difference